# Create a new database on running a Grails Application

Tags: grails, database-connection

Following are the configuration-details of Datasource.groovy :

```
development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" 
            url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDb"
        }
    }
```

This configuration works fine if database in manually created. Tried dbCreate="create-drop" or "update" or "create" but none of them creates a new database.
Also tried "CREATE DATABASE mydb" from a service but it gives an error reporting that "CREATE DATABASE not allowed from transaction block".

Any other method to avoid creating the database manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `dbCreate` attribute is to specify whether do you want to create/update the schema i.e. tables for an existing database or not. It's not going to create a new database.

Different values for `dbCreate`:

`create`: On startup of your application, this will drop and recreate your schema. This will make sure that you will always have a clean table structure, and all your data is reset on every startup.

`create-drop` - This will behave exactly like create when starting up your application, with addition that it will drop all your tables when the application is shut down properly or gracefully.

`update` - Synch the database schema with your current data model.

`validate` - just compare your data model with the database on start up and create warnings if necessary.

Regarding:

> Any other method to avoid creating the database manually.

Create a shell script, that creates your db before you start the application.

**Update 1:**

If you are so willing to create a database during app startup only, then you can create a new `Sql` object and execute your query before creation of `dataSource` bean. for e.g., inside a config file, as config files are parsed before creation of `dataSource` bean.

```
try {
    groovy.sql.Sql sql = groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306", "root", "root", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    sql.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS MyDB")
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

Comment: Just migrating from MongoDb to Postgres,  the current mongoDb approach is using a library method that creates a database when we access it using mongo.getDb("myDb").I need a similar library method for postgres.

Comment: And regarding the shell script, we are not sure about the deployment process of the application.

Comment: DB creation is a one time process and can be done manually. See this answer by Burt Beckwith: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19479867/1799527

Comment: Yes, that is fine, but as per the requirements whenever the application/ project is executed on a machine in the proper environment it must create the DB itself.

Comment: Also, just adding again, in the mongoDb approach the Db is created by the application itself and needs to do same even with the postgres database

Comment: I have already tried that, database is created but the application is not able to use that i.e tables are created in the default postgres database.

Comment: I tried it with mysql, and its working. Should work with postgres. Make sure you are creating the db before dataSource bean gets initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Use ***END;*** before your query so that if any transaction is open it will be ended and your problem will be resolved.